# AWS SDK v3 can't get region from profile

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm initializing an s3 client with credentials coming from a profile in the shared ini file. I'd like to setup the default region using the same.

`~\.aws\credentials`

```ini
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
```

`~\.aws\config`

```ini
[profile myprofile]
region = eu-west-1
```

My code

```js
import {S3} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import {fromIni} from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers';

const s3Client = new S3({
   credentials: fromIni({
        profile: 'myprofile',
   }),
});
await s3Client.listBuckets({});
```

The error I'm getting is `Error: Region is missing` and the output of calling `fromIni` is

```js
{
  accessKeyId: '...',
  secretAccessKey: '...',
  sessionToken: undefined
}
```

Why region isn't loaded from the shared config file?

---

**UPDATE**

`fromIni` docs notes that

> Profiles that appear in both files will not be merged, and the version that appears in the credentials file will be given precedence over the profile found in the config file.

Apart from the obvious break from the usual [configuration standards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-format.html), moving `region` from `config` to `credentials` generates the same error.

`~\.aws\credentials`

```ini
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
region = eu-west-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loadSharedConfigFiles` helper can read a profile's default region from the local config files, which you can then pass to the client constructor:

```js
import { fromIni } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers';
import { loadSharedConfigFiles } from '@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader';

const profile = 'myprofile';

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  credentials: fromIni({ profile }),
  region: (await loadSharedConfigFiles()).configFile?.[profile]?.region,
});
```

The `configFile` property loads `~/aws/config` and `credentialsFile` loads `~/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: Shouldn't the SDK v3 load the region from either the config file or env variable by default as mentoned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-region.html) ?

Comment: @PreetNagda OP needs programatic access to an \*arbitrary\* profile's region, not the \*default\* profile's region.

Answer (score 0):

The [S3 Constructor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/s3clientconfig.html) uses the region property on the the level of the configuration object as `credentials`, thus you should use something like:

```
const s3Client = new S3({
   credentials: fromIni({
        profile: 'myprofile',
   }),
   region: 'eu-west-1'
});
```

The [fromIni](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_credential_providers.html#fromini) doc doesn't talks about region, I guess it is not meant for this.

About loading the config file, I think you are looking for the environment variable `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE`, [see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html#setting-region-config-file) (didn't test it though).
However, as @CherryDT commented, you may want to declare it explicitly, it may change depending on the situation.

Comment: Fair enough. `region` is not part of the `CredentialsProvider` object. How to get the region (or other global configs) from the shared file though? By hand?

Comment: The region in the config file is just a default for convenient use with CLI, much like the output format. In code, you are supposed to know what region you want to operate on, as there may be multiple.